# Spotify player undefined in react useState

Tags: reactjs, spotify

Hi I'm trying to make an Spotify player using react, actually everything ok but I want when I go back that stop sound from playin

```
export default function WebPlayback(props) {
    
    const [player,setPlayer] = useState();

    useEffect( () => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
        script.async = true;
    
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
            const player = new window.Spotify.Player({
                name: 'Musilapp',
                getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(props.access_token); },
                volume: 0.5
            });    
            setPlayer(player)
            player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }) => {
                let data = JSON.stringify({"context_uri": `${props.album_uri}`,"position_ms": 0})
                let config = { 
                    headers:{
                        "Accept":"application/json",
                        "Content-Type":"application/json",
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${props.access_token}`
                    },
                }
                axios.put(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=${device_id}`,data,config)
            });

            player.addListener('player_state_changed', ({position,duration,track_window: { current_track }}) => {
                props.setCurrentTrack(current_track)
            });
            player.connect();
        };

        return () =>{
            console.log(player)
        }
    },[]);

   

   return (
       <></>
   );
}
```

I got this principally from the spotify documentation, but the issue is player is still undefined on the unmount event fired by useEffect.

Update also all event as togglePlay, pause ect is undefined even after the init of player
Any idea ?

Comment: try extracting the method that sets current state (setCurrentStack) and call api outside the `useEffect` and make sure to use `async` I think. `const playTrack = async () => { ... your code } ` Also use `await` before the `axios.put`and then in `useEffect` just runthe function you created. Let me know if this works. At the end just let `useEffect( () => { playTrack() }, []);`

Comment: Thx for your reply, I try what you meen but nothing change